# T-SQL - combine multiple rows into one using timestamp

Tags: t-sql, join, unix-timestamp

I am trying to combine multiple rows into one based on a unix timestamp which I created from a datetime using a self created scalar function.

I need to modify the T-SQL below so that lines that have the same timestamp are displayed on one row rather than multiple:

```
USE [NDTMS2Utils]

GO

SELECT [Timestamp], 
[Logger], 
[KeyIndicator], 
[GeographicArea],
CASE 
    WHEN LocalAuthority = '- Restricted' THEN 'No LA Selected - Restricted' 
    WHEN LocalAuthority = '- Public' THEN 'No LA Selected - Public' 
    ELSE LocalAuthority 
END AS LocalAuthority, 
CASE 
    WHEN SubstanceGroup = '- Restricted' THEN 'All - Restricted' 
    WHEN SubstanceGroup = '- Public' THEN 'All - Public' 
    ELSE SubstanceGroup 
END AS SubstanceGroup,
CASE 
    WHEN Gender = '- Restricted' THEN 'All - Restricted' 
    WHEN Gender = '- Public' THEN 'All - Public' 
    ELSE Gender 
END AS Gender, 
CASE 
    WHEN AgeGroup = '- Restricted' THEN 'All - Restricted' 
    WHEN AgeGroup = '- Public' THEN 'All - Public' 
    ELSE AgeGroup 
END AS AgeGroup   
FROM (
SELECT [dbo].[UNIX_TIMESTAMP]([Date]) AS [Timestamp], 
[Logger], 
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Key Indicator%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [KeyIndicator],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Region%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [GeographicArea],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Area%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [LocalAuthority],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Substance Category%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [SubstanceGroup],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Gender%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [Gender],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%AgeGroup%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [AgeGroup]
FROM [Log] 
WHERE (Message LIKE '%ViewIt - View Data - the selected%') AND Logger != ''
GROUP BY [Date], [Logger], [Message]

UNION ALL

SELECT [dbo].[UNIX_TIMESTAMP]([Date]) AS [Timestamp], 
'Public', 
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Key Indicator' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Public') END AS [KeyIndicator],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Region%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Public') END AS [GeographicArea],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Area%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [LocalAuthority],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Substance Category%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [SubstanceGroup],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%Gender%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [Gender],
CASE WHEN [Message] LIKE '%AgeGroup%' THEN LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX(':', [Message]), LEN([Message])), ':', '') + ' - Restricted') END AS [AgeGroup]
FROM [Log]
WHERE (Message LIKE '%ViewIt - View Data - the selected%') AND Logger = ''
GROUP BY [Date], [Logger], [Message]
) AS f
ORDER BY CONVERT([Date], GETDATE()) ASC, [Logger]
```

Currently the data looks like this when the above query is run:

[image]

The table below shows the format that I am trying achieve:

[image]

How do I modify the query to display the results above?

Comment: You should get the right results on your outermost query grouping by TimeStamp and Logger then wrapping all the other columns in MIN or MAX.

Comment: Use CTE, ROW_NUMBER(in cte for generat query main) and then use MAX OR MIN Function for select from cte cube and use max and min... I guess this way it's usable for u.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple CROSS TAB problem, note [this article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%E2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1) by Jeff Moden.

Since you don't have any DDL or easily consumable sample data I created my own simplified sample data that should be enough.

```
-- Sample Table
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE 
(
  TStamp BIGINT,
  Logger VARCHAR(40),
  Pet    VARCHAR(20),
  Car    VARCHAR(30),
  Fruit  VARCHAR(20)
);

-- Sample Data
INSERT @yourtable (TStamp,Logger,Pet,Car,Fruit)
VALUES
(154377379, '07F09981-C723-4DB3-A4C4-2842F26D102A',NULL,NULL,'Apple'),
(154377379, '07F09981-C723-4DB3-A4C4-2842F26D102A',NULL,'Porche',NULL),
(154377379, '07F09981-C723-4DB3-A4C4-2842F26D102A','Cat',NULL,NULL),
(151173333, '84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422',NULL,NULL,'Orange'),
(151173333, '84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422',NULL,'Subaru',NULL),
(151173333, '84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422','Frog',NULL,NULL),
(151177855, '84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422',NULL,NULL,'Grapes'),
(151177855, '84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422',NULL,'Hovercraft',NULL),
(151177855, '84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422','Bird',NULL,NULL);

-- Solution
SELECT   
  TStamp = t.TStamp,
  Logger = T.Logger, 
  Pet    = MAX(CASE WHEN t.Pet   IS NOT NULL THEN t.Pet   END),
  Car    = MAX(CASE WHEN t.Car   IS NOT NULL THEN t.Car   END),
  Fruit  = MAX(CASE WHEN t.Fruit IS NOT NULL THEN t.Fruit END)
FROM     @yourtable AS t
GROUP BY t.TStamp, t.Logger;
```

**Results:**

```
TStamp      Logger                                   Pet    Car          Fruit
----------- ---------------------------------------- ------ ------------ --------
154377379   07F09981-C723-4DB3-A4C4-2842F26D102A     Cat    Porche       Apple
151173333   84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422     Frog   Subaru       Orange
151177855   84BEDA9D-D525-4A95-B1D7-4D9A74EB0422     Bird   Hovercraft   Grapes
```